# react-bootstrap-table-next: minimum required column width

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, width, react-bootstrap-table

Use a table `react-bootstrap-table-next`. There are columns in the table where there is very little text. How do I set the table properties so that such columns are as wide as the text, but no wider?

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can do that by setting style and header style inside columns

```
   headerStyle: (colum, colIndex) => {
        return { display: "inline-flex" };
      },
   style: {
        display: "inline-flex"
      }
```